# useEffect clears, then refills my react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have two used state arrays were going to call them queries, and messages.

```
  const [queries, setQueries] = useState([]);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

I have it so when users type a search query it will add the query to a list of queries on screen. When the user deletes one of those queries or adds a new query, my use state will read the last query on the list and run a fetch request all within the useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (queries.length > 0) {
      const [x] = queries.slice(-1);
      axios
        .get(`FETCH REQUEST`)
        .then((res) => {
          setMessages(res.data.messages);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      setMessages([]); // <-- this right here is my problem!
    }   
  }, [queries]);
```

The problem is everything works as it should until the there are no items in the array. It will briefly return an empty message array, then fetch request the last deleted item anyway somehow. Form what I can conclude this is where the problem is located, but I do not understand the why or how despite trying to force my result in various ways. Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Is `setMsg`, `setMessage`, and `setMessages` supposed to represent the same function?

Comment: yes pardon my sloppyness. Ill make a quick edit!

Answer (score 1):

The setState function works asynchronously, if required, would join multiple requests without any specific order to optimize the app performance. This could trigger useEffect multiple times and set your message state incorrectly. Instead, you can set the message state using a callback into the setQueries call.

```
function cbAddOrDeleteQuery() {
  ...  
  setQueries(_ => {
    // newVal represents the updated queries
    if (newVal.length > 0) {      
      setMessage(res.data.messages);
    } else {
      setMessage([]);
    }

    return newVal;
  });
}
```